# How can I login to a Docker registry which also has basic auth?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to access a Docker registry which has a nginx in front. This nginx has basic authentication enabled. I tried to login with `docker login url-of-registry` but it doesn't seem to work. I always get:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://docker-registry-url/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

I would expect that I first have to enter the basic auth credentials and then the Docker registry credentials. How can I login to such Docker registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is documented under [Authenticate proxy with nginx](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/#starting-and-stopping). You can find there the syntax to authorize to the registry behind the nginx proxy.

Comment: Thank you, I must have overlooked that. I will try it out.